# Memory issue when trying to use minZoom on XYZ source

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to set a minimum zoom at which to show an XYZ source in my map in OpenLayers, but whenever I set it, the whole map has a memory issue and crashes. maxZoom works just fine.

I was originally using OpenLayers in React, but after running into this issue, I stripped it down as much as possible to see if I could fix it (I couldn't). Here's my code now:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ.js';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: 'http://myserver.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}/',
        minZoom: 14,
        maxZoom: 19
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3
  })
});
```

What I'm intending to happen is to have the map load at zoom level 3, then when you zoom to level 14 the myserver.com tiles start showing. With the code as above, the page just loads and loads until Chrome says "Paused before potential out-of-memory crash" (basically the same for Firefox). If I take out this line:

```
minZoom: 14,
```

it loads fine. I've tried setting the minZoom to different values with no luck.

Comment: When opening at zoom 3 you are loading all the tiles needed to cover that extent at zoom 14.  That's 2**12 times the normal load for zoom 3.  To achieve what you want set the `maxResolution` option on the layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That's very helpful. I don't fully understand, though, what exactly it's the resolution of? I just want these tiles to load between zoom 14 and 19, so what resolutions do I need? Is it dependent on viewport size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maxResolution will be the resolution of the tiles at zoom level 14.  It's exclusive so increase it slightly to include level 14, then the layer will only visible at level 14 and more

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ.js';
import {createXYZ} from 'ol/tilegrid';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: 'http://myserver.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}/',
        maxZoom: 19
      }),
      maxResolution: createXYZ().getResolution(14) * 1.01
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3
  })
});
```

If you want the layer to remain visible but show no addition detail after zoom 19 `maxZoom: 19` is sufficient.  If don't want it to be visible set `minResolution: createXYZ().getResolution(19)` on the layer (minResolution is inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but I managed to solve it. The `minZoom` attribute should be provided to the layer, not the source. So instead of

```js
new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: 'http://myserver.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}/',
        minZoom: 14,
        maxZoom: 19
      })
    })
```

write

```js
new TileLayer({
      minZoom: 14,
      source: new XYZ({
        url: 'http://myserver.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}/',
        maxZoom: 19
      })
    })
```

I'm not sure about what's the deal with `maxZoom`, but I hope this will help someone forward